# The method 'containsKey' isn't defined for the type 'function'. How can I fix it?

Tags: flutter, dart, maps

```
    var data = {
      'photoUrl': profileImageUrl,
      'age': age,
      'username': username,
    };
    //ref.setData(data, merge: true);
    ref.set(data);
    SetOptions(merge: true);
    final DocumentSnapshot currentDocument = await ref.get();
    return Utilizer.fromFirestore(currentDocument);
  }
 @override
  Future<bool> isProfileComplete(String uid) async {
    DocumentReference ref = fireStoreDb.collection(Paths.usersPath).doc(uid);
    final DocumentSnapshot currentDocument = await ref.get();

    return (currentDocument.exists &&
        
        currentDocument.data.containsKey('username') &&  //error here
        currentDocument.data.containsKey('age'));        //error here
```

> I'm new to flutter and OOP. This was some project tutorial I was following. But the version of the flutter used in the project is deprecated. So I was upgrading it and encountered this problem. It seems the previous versions didn't have problem with this. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

`data` property on [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) is a method that returns the contents of the document snapshot. You need to execute it before you can access Map's properties.

```
currentDocument.data().containsKey('username')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But now it says, 'The method 'containsKey' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.'

Comment: You may want to try casting it to map `as Map<String, dynamic>` or adding typing info - DocumentSnapshot/DocumentReference has generic attribute T - `DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>`